# Concatenation of dynamic value and default value in custom annotation

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, annotations, spring-annotations

I have one custom annotation, I want to have default value of requestmapping as "/api/contracts" and to pass dynamic value which will concatenate to the path.
Example I'm passing "/something" to custom annotation it should act like "/api/contracts/something"

My custom annotation is

```
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/contracts")
public @interface IfnContractRequestMapping
{
    @AliasFor(annotation = RequestMapping.class, attribute = "value") String[] value() default {};

}
```

And I'm passing value to it as `@IfnContractRequestMapping(value = "/something")`

Comment: Isn’t that pretty much the same as using `@RequestMapping(“/api/contracts”)` at the class level and `@RequestMapping(“/something”)` at the method level? If this functionality isn’t sufficient, you could look up the source code to find out how they concatenate the two and adapt it to your annotation.

Comment: I have multiple controllers which extends @RequestMapping("/api/contracts") and has there own extended path. I'm not using this for method.